# ListView communication between elements

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a ListView, a CustomAdapter, and an xml file "row_layout" that defines a row for the ListView. The "row_layout" has a TextView and a Button. My question is upon clicking the Button, how can I get access information from its corresponding TextView? Currently, I am getting the information from the textview in the last row of listview.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
     private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     private Context context;
     View view;

public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context) {
      this.list = list;
      this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
    }

    //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
    Button myButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.myButton);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //DOES NOT WORK HERE AS PLANNED
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return view;
    }

}

}
```

The following is the xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/root">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/myTextView"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/myButton"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace

```
TextView tv = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
```

with

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
```

You find the Textview which belongs to your actual **row** (in your code the variable `view`), not in your base layout.

Edit: Your Inflate should be

```
view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that but I'm still getting the information from the textview in the last row of listview.

Answer (score 1):

Replace This

```
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
```

With :

```
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,convertView,false);
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: You should not attach the inflated xml to root view by passing false argument to third argument

Comment: an explanation would be appreciated @AmirshayanAghamiri

Comment: Add these public String getItem(int position){return list.get(position);} public int getCount(){return list.size();} to your Custom adapter class and set the TextView text by calling its setText method and pass the getItem(position) as its argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
view = convertView;
if (view == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
//Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
Button myButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
TextView textview = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);}

myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //DOES NOT WORK HERE AS PLANNED
        textview.getText().toString();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});

return view;
}
```